# Configurate Keymap of PHPStorm like Sublime Text

Tags: configuration, phpstorm, sublimetext, keymaps

When I tried to modify the keymap of PHPStorm to work like Sublime Text. I found a lot of conflict

There is any keymap configuration of PHPStorm like Sublime Text ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We don't have a predefined Sublime keymap yet, please vote for [IDEA-111333](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-111333).
A quick search has revealed something contributed by the community, you can give it a try: https://github.com/ProLoser/IntelliJ-SubliMate .